# Parameter to isolate frames with colored lines

Tags: opencv

I'm writing a code that should detect frames in a video that have colored lines. I'm new to openCV and would like to know if I should evaluate saturation, entropy, RBG intensity, etc. The lines, as shown in the pictures, come in every color and density. When black and white, but they are all the same color inside a given frame. Any advice?

Regular frame:

[image: Regular frame]

Example 1:

[image: Example 1]

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: You forgot to add the images.

Comment: I would convert to HSV and then take the mean Saturation as a first attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to get the mean Saturation and see that it is lower for your greyscale image and higher for your colour ones:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cv2

# Open image
im =cv2.imread('a.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Convert to HSV
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get mean Saturation - I use index "1" because Hue is index "0" and Value is index "2"
meanSat = hsv[...,1].mean()
```

**Results**

```
first image (greyish):  meanSat = 78
second image (blueish): meanSat = 162
third image (redish):   meanSat = 151
```

If it is time-critical, I guess you could just calculate for a small extracted patch since the red/blue lines are all over the image anyway.